# PDFBox: How to prevent pdf pages from being auto rotated before print?

Tags: java, pdf, printing, pdfbox

I'm trying to print a PDF using PDFbox library. But the resultant print is rotated by 90 degrees. The page size is 70mm x 17mm but the print lenght is of the form 17mm x 70mm.

```
String filename = dest; 
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File (filename));

    PrintService myPrintService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(document));
    job.setPrintService(myPrintService);
    if(job.printDialog())
        job.print();
    document.close();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `Orientation` enum to `PDFPageable` constructor:

```
job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(document, Orientation.PORTRAIT) );
```

Since you are using non-standard paper, the default orientation value of `Orientation.AUTO` is interpreting shorter edges as top and bottom.

Comment: I'm getting an error. It says There is no such function as setPageable( arg1 , arg2);

Comment: yeah, you pass it to PDFPageable constructor - code fixed now

Comment: which problem? original problem or the compilation problem? If it is the orientation, try passing `Orientation.PORTRAIT`

Comment: I meant the original problem not the compilation one. So after using PORTRAIT there is a change. Here are the images before and after using protrait http://i.imgur.com/SLb3ENK.png and http://i.imgur.com/IQ20YGm.png . Landscape orientation had no effect but portrait at least rotated the image.

Comment: I suspect that this is the problem mentioned in issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3117 . There is a workaround but it requires downloading the source code of `PDFPageable` copy it and change it, see last comment in link.